# C++ RFC3339 timestamp with milliseconds using std::chrono

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono, rfc3339

I'm creating an [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) timestamp, including milliseconds and in UTC, in C++ using `std::chrono` like so:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

string now_rfc3339() {
  const auto now = system_clock::now();
  const auto millis = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count() % 1000;
  const auto c_now = system_clock::to_time_t(now);

  stringstream ss;
  ss << put_time(gmtime(&c_now), "%FT%T") <<
    '.' << setfill('0') << setw(3) << millis << 'Z';
  return ss.str();
}

// output like 2019-01-23T10:18:32.079Z
```

(forgive the `using`s)

Is there a more straight forward way of getting the milliseconds of `now`? It seems somewhat cumbersome to `%1000` the `now` in milliseconds to get there. Or any other comments on how to do this more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with subtraction:

```
string
now_rfc3339()
{
    const auto now_ms = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
    const auto now_s = time_point_cast<seconds>(now_ms);
    const auto millis = now_ms - now_s;
    const auto c_now = system_clock::to_time_t(now_s);

    stringstream ss;
    ss << put_time(gmtime(&c_now), "%FT%T")
       << '.' << setfill('0') << setw(3) << millis.count() << 'Z';
    return ss.str();
}
```

This avoids the "magic number" 1000.

Also, there is [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, single-header, header-only datetime library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h):

```
string
now_rfc3339()
{
    return date::format("%FT%TZ", time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now()));
}
```

This does the same thing but with easier syntax.

Comment: Thanks Howard, stumbled across your date lib already, it looks very helpful! I'll keep it in mind for the future. But in this project, there's only one place where I need that format, so I rather not include an external source for that.